# is there a way to check where my player can only Jump once

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a platformer game in unity 2D where my I'm trying to make my character have a slight hangtime delay falling down whenever players reached the edge of a platform they will have a small amount of time to jump. However if jump button is press twice quickly the character makes a double jump, character only needs to jump once if not falling on the edge of the platform.

[Screenshot scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52ihu.png)

Here is what I have done so far for my jumping mechanics:

```
float Hangtime;
float HangCounter = .3f;        

void Update () {        
    JumpRequest();        
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    HangtimeImplents();
    Jump();
    
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feet.position, groundradius, groundlayers);    
}

// For Jump --------------

void HangtimeImplents() { 
    if (isGrounded) // checks if grounded is true then hangtime is always .3f
    {
        Hangtime = HangCounter;         
    }
    else
    {
        Hangtime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

public void JumpRequest() {
    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Hangtime > 0f) // checks if Jump Button is pressed and Hangtime is greated than 0
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        Jumprequest = true;
    }
}








void Jump() // Jump Function if Jumprequest is true
{
    if (Jumprequest)
    {
        mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce) , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    
    }

    Jumprequest = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but the easiest ways is updating the code like this:

```
if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Hangtime == HangCounter) // checks if Jump Button is pressed and Hangtime is greated than 0
{
    isGrounded = false;
    Jumprequest = true;
}
```

On your code, `Time.deltaTime` is less than the frame completion time.
So even `isGrounded` is false, `Hangtime` is still greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Make an operator called jumpTimes

public int maximizeJumpTimes;

private int jumpTimes

When the player jump, Minus the jumpTimes; and if the jumpTimes == 0 make the player can't jump.

Hope this help :>